# performances evaluation of image classification with different distribution for train and test set

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, image-classification

I am implementing a CNN to do image classification of 4 classes representing different weathers : Haze, Sunny, Rainy, Snowy. I have as training set 3200 images, and as test set 3038 images.

The problem is that the test and training set are different set of pictures(so to be clear, I didn't split the dataset, but I have been given a training set and a test set in different folders) and they have so a different distribution one with respect to the other.

After training and evaluating, I have that my accuracy on the test set is 0.475313 and the loss always on the test set is 3.060471.

Also if I plot the hihstory of accuracy and of the loss I have the following:

[image]

what I don't understand is if I have the accuracy so low because I am overfitting, or because the distribution is different. And also, how do I interpret the plots I have posted about the histories of loss and accuracy? Is it normal that the gap between test and train accuracy is so large?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] By searching online, I have found that to cope with this kind of problems, it is possible to use domain adaptation, but honestly I have no idea how to implement it because I have just read about it.

Comment: Can't you merge those sets and do stratified splits yourself? Could you please upload bar char of class balance in your sets? What architecture are you using? Are you training net from scratch?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am training a CNN from scratch and also I have a balanced dataset. The problem is that the distribution between the test and train is different, so I am not ableto go above the accuracy I wrote in the question.

Comment: Which architecture are you using? What is your augmentation procedure?

Comment: I am using a network with 8 convolutional layers and 3 dense layers.  As augmentation, what I am doing is shifting and flipping the images. I am also rescaling them because they are not all of the same size.

Comment: What is the shape of input image?

Comment: In origin the have all different scales, but I reshaped as 256 x 256 for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How different is the test set from train set, like better/poorer quality? Can you do something to make them similar?
And, you might be overfitting the train data. As suggested by piotr rarus, use data augmentation and transfer learning. Also, use early stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have too little data. That's why optimizer can't converge to any reasonable place. I'd suggest you try doing transfer learning first. Few links for you to check out:

- https://machinelearningmastery.com/transfer-learning-for-deep-learning/
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/20/transfer-learning-with-keras-and-deep-learning/
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/06/24/change-input-shape-dimensions-for-fine-tuning-with-keras/
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/06/03/fine-tuning-with-keras-and-deep-learning/

Consider also heavier augmentation. [Albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) is a nice repo, used in many kaggle competitions.

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution of the test and training sets are different, the metrics will be fairly different. And in cases of imbalanced classes, accuracy is not a great measure. Consider using precision, recall, or f-score. See if they improve over epochs.